# cloneNode() changes attribute value in InternetExplorer 10 and 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg, clone

When I call `cloneNode()` on an element with the name `feGaussianBlur` that has the attribute `stdDeviation`, InternetExplorer (10 and 11) always converts the value to `1.72443e+009`.

Here is a four-liner that illustrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kytbh4Ls/6/

If you change the element name, use a different attribute name or run the fiddle on any other browser (Chrome, Firefox), everything runs as expected. Using a different attribute value will not change anything.

What could be the reason for this really strange behaviour? And is there something that can be done about it?

Here a modified fiddle using jQuery's `clone()` instead of `cloneNode()`, unfortunately producing the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/kytbh4Ls/7/

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Report it to Microsoft. http://blog.reybango.com/2013/02/28/submitting-an-internet-explorer-bug-to-microsoft/

Comment: You mean, regardless of the value it previously had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clear bug in Internet Explorer. While it is true that Internet Explorer uses the `stdDeviation` instead of `stdDeviationX` and `stdDeviationY`, the `cloneNode()` function has no business in messing around with the attributes. It should return a clone of the node, not a node with changed attributes.

You should report this to the Internet Explorer development team (if you have the the time to do so). Currently all you can probably do is to implement a manual workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE does not use the stdDeviation attribute.  Instead it uses stdDeviationX and stdDeviationY.

See this fiddle...  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/incept0/voc6t46v/2/)

Here is the [Microsoft page for feGaussianBlur](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh773246(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
var element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "feGaussianBlur");
element.setAttribute('stdDeviationX', 5);
element.setAttribute('stdDeviationY', 5);

var clonedElement = element.cloneNode();

alert("Original:" + element.getAttribute("stdDeviationX") + ", Cloned:" + clonedElement.getAttribute("stdDeviationX"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but stdDeviationX and stdDeviationY do not work in SVGs on InternetExplorer. The correct attribute is stdDeviation. Here is a very simple SVG that compares the attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/1vkn22bp/

As you can see, only stdDeviation gives the desired effect.

Also, even if stdDeviation was not supported, there is no reason for the browser to change the attribute value on cloning.

Comment: Notorious is right. IE uses stdDeviationX  and stdDeviationY. What's stopping you from setting the stdDeviation on the cloned element like clonedElement.setAttribute("stdDeviation", 5);

Comment: I don't know what version IE you're testing in but in IE11 `stdDeviationX` and `stdDeviationY` does not work, while `stdDeviation` gives the effect but breaks when cloning.